# Is there any saying about "Bindi" anywhere in the Qur'an or hadith?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-philosophy

I have a very strange question according to what my title says. This was confusing me for a very long and it's unclear to me. I just kept myself away from researching about it.

However, I came across a situation where one of my office colleague's who's a Muslim and his wife was using a sticker on her forehead (known as "[Bindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindi_(decoration))", if that's what its called). I didn't wanted to embarrass them asking such strange questions. In fact, I have very little knowledge regarding this.

So, my question is; Does the Qur'an or hadith specifically mention about this sort of scenarios? If so, please provide me answers with references.

[image: Indian woman with bindi]

(Image source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Indian_Woman_with_bindi.jpg))

Comment: Salam,These are cultural practices where there are influences of others  so it has nothing to do with Islam.JazakAllah

Comment: I do know this has nothing to do with islam. But if you read my question, I have asked for clarification on when Muslim practices it whether knowing or not knowing.

Comment: Having a bindi on forehead will be a hindrance when talking ablution and when doing prostration in prayer. Also, isn't this imitating people of other culture ? so I think better to avoid it.

Comment: @AbuZiyad - Exactly! I recall on of the incident where our beloved Propher Muhammadh S.A.Q (PBUH) use teach us as to be the opposite of what a Kafir does by pointing out mustache, beard... etc, if I'm not mistaken... Moving further, I do know avoiding is better but do we have any facts, hadeeths, or similar sayings within?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any hadith or verse of Qur'an that specifically says anything about bindi. It is generally worn by Hindu and Jain women of India. So, it's better to avoid it but there is no evidence in the hadith or the Qur'an that specifically prohibits it. And Allah knows best.

Further reading: [Islamqa.org | Fatwa: 43506](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/43506).